# SSAS MDX calculation filter

Tags: filter, ssas, mdx

I would like to do something like this (tsql):

```
select saldi
where rek in (4,8)
 and rek5  <> 41111 
 and rek3  not in (a,b,c)
```

Following MDX, filter (4,8) <> 41111, is not working. If I remove the 41111 filter the measure works fine, just shows 4/8. Adding 41111 as a '<>' filter and the result is blank, not even 0.00.

```
THIS = IIF(
   ( [Rekeningen].[Rek n1].CurrentMember  = [Rekeningen].[Rek n1].&[4]
        or [Rekeningen].[Rek n1].CurrentMember  =  [Rekeningen].[Rek n1].&[8] )
   and [Rekeningen].[Rek n5].CurrentMember <> [Rekeningen].[Rek n5].&[41111]
,
   [Measures].[Saldi], 0.00
);
```

I tried Google, but don't seem to get the keyword right. On social.msdn.microsoft.com a lot of reactions are marked as answer, but not for me this far.
Deploying the ssas cube works fine, no errors.

Can anybody point me in the right direction? I tried [Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144900.aspx), but that command doesn't seem to work with multile fields(rek3/rek5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IS` and `NOT IS` are used when comparing members. That gives us this:

```
THIS = 
  IIF
  (
      (
        [Rekeningen].[Rek n1].CurrentMember IS [Rekeningen].[Rek n1].&[4]
      OR 
        [Rekeningen].[Rek n1].CurrentMember is [Rekeningen].[Rek n1].&[8]
      )
    AND 
      [Rekeningen].[Rek n5].CurrentMember IS NOT [Rekeningen].[Rek n5].&[41111]
   ,[Measures].[Saldi]
   ,0
  );
```

Rather than `0` you should nearly always use `null` in cube script calcs or you'll kill performance:

```
THIS = 
  IIF
  (
      (
        [Rekeningen].[Rek n1].CurrentMember IS [Rekeningen].[Rek n1].&[4]
      OR 
        [Rekeningen].[Rek n1].CurrentMember is [Rekeningen].[Rek n1].&[8]
      )
    AND 
      [Rekeningen].[Rek n5].CurrentMember IS NOT [Rekeningen].[Rek n5].&[41111]
   ,[Measures].[Saldi]
   ,NULL
  );
```

I'm not convinced about these member names? `[Rekeningen].[Rek n1].CurrentMember` and `[Rekeningen].[Rek n1].&[4]`. Let me add the two alternatives that I think they might be:

1.

```
THIS = 
  IIF
  (
      (
        [Rekeningen].[Rek n1].CurrentMember IS [Rekeningen].[Rek n1].[Rek n1].&[4]
      OR 
        [Rekeningen].[Rek n1].CurrentMember is [Rekeningen].[Rek n1].[Rek n1].&[8]
      )
    AND 
      [Rekeningen].[Rek n5].CurrentMember IS NOT [Rekeningen].[Rek n5].[Rek n5].&[41111]
   ,[Measures].[Saldi]
   ,NULL
  );
```

or

2.

```
THIS = 
  IIF
  (
      (
        [Rekeningen].CurrentMember IS [Rekeningen].[Rek n1].&[4]
      OR 
        [Rekeningen].CurrentMember is [Rekeningen].[Rek n1].&[8]
      )
    AND 
      [Rekeningen].CurrentMember IS NOT [Rekeningen].[Rek n5].&[41111]
   ,[Measures].[Saldi]
   ,NULL
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.

@whytheq Got parse errors, should this not be "IS NOT"?

Will mark this as answer because resolved the problem, however it did not functionally do what I wanted in the cube. I'll rethink & rephrase my question and post a new one.

Comment: @FabioBruna apologies for the parse errors - I've edited the answer. Yes quite often I get mdx that runs ok but does not return the number I expect: usually I then split the script up into much smaller chunks and test them to see what data they return ... then increase the complexity more.. until it is "behaving" as expected.